# Uninstalling Ubuntu. Which partitions to delete?

Tags: partitioning, uninstall

I installed Ubuntu successfully, however something went wrong and I could boot neither Ubuntu or Windows 8, I was forced to reset the computer.

I now believe Ubuntu and all its associated software is gone, and now I just need to delete the partitions it was on. However, I do not know which partitions to delete without damaging windows.

My partitions in disk management look like this.

[image]

Ubuntu automatically made the partitions during the installation and I do not know which ones to remove. For now I no longer want Ubuntu, though I may come back to it at a later date.

Comment: By the way, the only thing I know is that the (C:) is my windows one with program files etc. in it.

Answer (score 1):

Hm. Deleting Ubuntu partitions should not be your priority right now. Try to reinstall it so you can get access to both Windows and Ubuntu. BTW, do you have some sort of RAID, why do you have two D: partitions ? And where did you install Ubuntu, you don't seem to have any partition big enough ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to boot into either, you've got a bigger problem, however it's the EFI and the 'Primary' ones that you want to get rid of.

to clarify: not the E: primary, the blank one beside the EFI.