# Removing Ubuntu from boot manager

Tags: boot, uefi, bios

I have a similar problem like in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi) post.

The answer there suggests using the 4 commands:

```
sudo apt-get install efibootmgr
sudo modprobe efivars
sudo efibootmgr
sudo efibootmgr -b X -B
```

At first, I had the boot manager looking like this: (2 Ubuntu entries)

[image: boot_manager_1]

I got a Live Ubuntu CD and booted from it to use **Try Ubuntu** and enter the above commands.

In **boot mode settings** I had 2 choices:

- Legacy Boot Mode, Secure Boot Off
- UEFI Boot Mode, Secure Boot Off

As in the picture:

[image: boot_mode_settings]

Choosing the first one, allowed me to boot from the CD and log into Ubuntu (Trial mode). There, in the terminal, I typed the above commands and on the 3rd one I got:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo efibootmgr Fatal: Couldn't open either sysfs or procfs directories for accessing EFI variables. Try 'modprobe efivars' as root
```

Reading online I found that I should boot with *UEFI* mode. I did (2nd option), and now I got no errors. I actually got:

```
...
Boot0002* ubuntu
...
Boot0004* ubuntu
...
```

so I deleted both of them using `sudo efibootmgr -b X -B`. I typed `sudo efibootmgr` to confirm there aren't any **ubuntu** entries left, and there was none.

Finally, I went back to **Boot Manager** to check if the problem is solved, and, unexpectedly, I found 1 **ubuntu** entry:

[image: boot_manager_2]

I tried booting again from the CD using **UEFI** but I couldn't; I got right into the `grub>`. So I typed `exit`, and it returned me back to **Boot Manager**:

[image: grub]

So why wasn't that entry removed although I removed it? And how do I *really* remove it?

Thanks

Comment: sounds like you used an x86 iso to try and fix a uefi problem, which is never going to work.

Comment: I don't think so. The file name is `ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso`

Comment: isn't an option in the bios to reset the UEFI boot to the factory mode?

Comment: Did you also delete ubuntu folder in the efi partition? If not UEFI may keep adding entries. Also if also installed in BIOS boot mode and then boot again in BIOS mode, you have grub in protective MBR and since the rest of grub in Ubuntu is missing your get errors. If booting in UEFI mode then what is in MBR does not matter.

Comment: @oldfred I don't think I deleted ubuntu folder in the EFI partition;  please see my question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/527863/how-to-know-which-partition-is-ubuntu-installed-on (and the answer I picked). And I don't understand what you're saying about the MBR...

Comment: Essentially just saying even if grub is still in MBR, as long as you boot in UEFI mode it does not matter. Generally we do not erase MBR, but just install a new boot loader. But if not using MBR whatever it there does not matter. But if you attempt to boot in BIOS mode it will see grub & start to load it and give errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to remove Ubuntu from the boot menu if You don't have it installed anymore.

Insert a Windows 8 / 8.1 DVD or USB device, with the Windows 8 / 8.1 installation files on it, into your computer.

Boot from the disc or USB device.

From the Windows Setup screen, tap on Next.

Tap on the Repair your computer link at the bottom of the window.

Advanced Startup Options will start, almost immediately.

The Advanced Startup Options menu in Windows 8 / 8.1 is the central fix-it location for the entire operating system.

From here you can access Windows 8 / 8.1 diagnostic and repair tools like refresh and reset Your PC, System Restore, Command Prompt, and much more.

Then choose Command Prompt

In the black screen type:

```
diskpart
```

and enter this command:

```
sel disk 0
```

Now that the first disk is selected we need to view all the partitions

```
list vol
```

Verify that the EFI partition is using the FAT32 file system then select the volume and assign a drive letter to it.

Let’s say your EFI partition is on Volume 0, the next thing you would type is:

```
sel vol 0
```

Then assign an arbitrary drive letter to the parition.  Let’s use r.

```
assign letter=r:
```

You should see a message saying:

```
 DiskPart successfully assigned the drive letter or mount point.
```

Exit the diskpart typing:

```
exit
```

You need to repair the boot record:

```
cd /d r:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\

bootrec /fixboot
```

Now You need to recreate the Boot Configuration Data (BCD) store:

```
ren BCD BCD.old

bcdboot c:\Windows /l en-us /s r: /f ALL
```

Now You reboot and should be all set.

Source: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/system-recovery-overview

Comment: In the "source" link it says "Applies for Windows 8.1" and I have Windows 8. Is that ok? And you mentioned creating a new partition 'r'. Shouldn't I delete it in the end? Also, i just listed the volumes and I don't see EFI under Label. I got 2 FAT32's and their Labels are ESP and DIAGS

Comment: Here's what I see after typing `sel vol 0`: http://i90.photobucket.com/albums/k274/alaa_137/volumes_zps30fb398f.jpg?t=1412354939